# Spring mvc calling jsp(with submit form action to controller and DAO) without login action

Tags: java, spring

I am newbie to spring mvc.

I am working in spring mvc project, which was developed by others and I am looking into it.

I want to have a page which needs to be accessed without login form in this existing project.

Whenever I called the following page http://localhost:8080/myProject/mypage.htm it always goes to http://localhost:8080/myProject/login.htm first and then I have to provide credentials to access that page.

Is it possible to visit that page without login action required?

In myPage.htm I have a form action to call that controller and DAO classes.

Also tiles has been used in this project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your `url-pattern` for DispatcherServlet in web.xml ?

Comment: Here I am adding it from web.xml  ... <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodedFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: Have you got a `<intercept-url>` rule set to `isAuthenticated()` ?

Comment: is your `mypage.htm` a public page ? If it's a private page i.e something which should be accessible only after login, then you should not try to circumvent that :)

Comment: I searched in web.xml and there is no text in that file.

Comment: Its under the path of  \src\main\webapp\views\dashboards\mypage.jsp

Comment: I'm assuming that your `mypage.jsp`  is a dashboard page that displays information related to logged users. is it correct ? or is it just a static page ?

Comment: Looking at your path, your page is not inside WEB-INF, so you can access it directly with `http://localhost:8080/myProject/views/dashboards/mypage.jsp` but as the structure implies, it's a dashboard something that's specific to a user or a group of users.

Comment: No, its not a loggedinuser basic page.  Its just a page with from having a submit button and textbox. in this textbox I have to enter a id, from this id, I need to get a value from table..

Comment: Then you can use the url I mentioned in my comment, as the file extension is `.jsp`, its not intercepted by your DispatcherServlet.

Comment: Can I get the values from table without a problem by this way? I am calling the controller called generateController.java for this page's submit button. This java class is in  src\main\java\com\mmf\controllers

Comment: Ya you should not have a problem if your form's action is having `.htm`, so that it can be intercepted by Spring and the corresponding controller can be invoked

Comment: HTH... Let's say if your mypage.jsp form submit goes to `retrieve,htm` and the corresponding controller needs the user to be logged-in, you are back to square one again. Also make sure that your `retrieve.htm` is not revealing some unauthorized information on form submit :-)

Comment: Exactly I am in the same scenario... my form submit goes to generate.htm. How may I handle this?

Comment: Well the ideal way to handle is to prompt the user to login, because even if you can skip this action, if there are checks related to authentication down the line, you'll have to bypass the authentication in all those cases which is not secure.

Comment: how may I skip this login, I have searched lot, but cant get a right way

Comment: It actually depends on how exactly are you checking if he's a logged-in user. It can be done at a Filter level or an interceptor configured to intercept every request to a controller. It can be even at the controller level, where in you'll have some BaseController with some method to check if it's a valid request and may be they're calling that login-check method in the first line of every other controller. It's hard to tell without looking at your entire app.

Comment: @Arkantos, In this case login interceptors been used. I am just skipping this. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed a login interceptor checking user is not null and I am able to get the url without issues as well as the controllers too...

Comment: Great you figured out the issue but pls make sure to test if this new URL is not introducing any security issues in your app :-)